# "Федеральная служба" — с прописной или строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> У этого подразделения Федеральной службы своя история.

*Федеральный* — с прописной или строчной (речь идет о службе государственной статистики)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря какой оттенок нужно придать предложению. Слово "федеральная" есть в официальном названии этой службы, поэтому написание с заглавной буквы возможно: это будет отсылкой к её формальному названию. Но и написание со строчной буквы не будет ошибкой, поскольку служба не только по названию является федеральной (= общегосударственной для РФ).